# Column width is not changed in jQuery datatable

Tags: jquery, datatables

I use the following code for getting data drom SQL Server and show it in jQuery datatable. I have 21 columns.

```
$('#userTable').DataTable({
                   "language": {
                       "oPaginate": {
                       "sFirst": "اول",
                       "sPrevious": "قبلی",
                       "sNext": "بعدی",
                       "sLast": "آخر"
                   },
                  "sLengthMenu": "نمایش _MENU_ ردیف در هر صفحه",
                   "sZeroRecords": "موردی یافت نشد!",
                   "sInfo": "نمایش _START_ تا _END_ از مجموع _TOTAL_ رکورد",
                   "sInfoEmpty": "نمایش 0 تا 0 از 0 رکورد",
                   "sInfoFiltered": "(فیلتر شده از _MAX_ رکورد)",
                   "sSearch": "جستجو:"},
                   "lengthMenu": [5, 10, 15, 20, 50 ],

                  "processing": true, // for show progress bar
                  "serverSide": true, // for process server side
                  "filter": true, // this is for disable filter (search box)
                  "ordering": false,
                  "orderMulti": false, // for disable multiple column at once
                  "dataSrc": "",
                  "fixedColumns": true,
                  "columnDefs": [
                            { width: 20, targets: 0 },
                            { width: 200, targets: 3 }
                        ],
                  "columns": [
                          {"data":"userId", width: '50px'},
                          {"data":"userName"},
                          {"data":"department"},
                          {"data":"farmType"},
                          {"data":"realm"},
                          {"data":"costCenterAccess", width: '200px'},
                          {"data":"workArea"},
                          {"data":"creationDate"},
                          {"data":"creationTime"},
                          {"data":"isAdmin"},
                          {"data":"isManager"},
                          {"data":"canSeeWorkShops"},
                          {"data":"canDelete"},
                          {"data":"canSendMessage"},
                          {"data":"canSeeNotification"},
                          {"data":"canSeeFiles"},
                          {"data":"isActive"},
                          {"data":"accessFailed"},
                          {"data":"lockoutEnabled"},
                          {"data":"lockoutEnd"},
                          {
                              data: null,
                              render: function(data, type, row) {
                              return `<a href='#' class='btn btn-info' onclick="EditUser('${row.userId}')"><i class="fa fa-trash-o" aria-hidden="true"></i> ویرایش</a>`;
                              }
                          }
                       ],

                  "ajax": {
                      "url": "/Admin/LoadUsersData",
                      "type": "POST",
                      "datatype": "json"
                  }
              });
```

But none of columns can be affected. In some columns, I have a long row of data and I need to increase that specific column size. How can I fix it?

Comment: In your `columnDefs`, give the widths a unit of measurement, e.g. instead of `width: 20` try `width: '20px'`.

Comment: @kmoser I tried it. No effect.

Comment: Please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/71317666/edit) to include sample data.